# Freemarker string highlighting

Tags: java, freemarker

I would like to highlight a part of the string with the searchedText string.

Exemple: 
I have a product reference abcDeFg (case sensitive) and someone search for product with reference "def". The result should be `abc<span class="hl">DeF</span>g`

Problem: the result should be the highlighted product reference (case sensitive)
Excepted result: `abc<span class='light'>DeF</span>g` 
My result: `abc<span class='light'>def</span>g` (def is minuscule)

Currently I am using

```
 <#assign prodRef = product.getReference()>
 <#if (prodRef?lower_case?index_of(searchedText?lower_case) > -1)>
   <#assign textToReplace = "<span class='light'>" + searchedText + "</span>">
   ${product.reference?replace(searchedText, textToReplace, "i")}
 </#if>
```

Can someone tell me how fix this issue?
Basically i need replace string function that will keep the case sensitiveness of the original reference.

Comment: `lower_case` isn't destructive; are you sure `searchedText` isn't lower-case before if gets to this?

Comment: 2nd line of my code does not impact reference of the product. Im just using it to find out if searchedText exists in the product reference.

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking you to make sure it's actually mixed-case before it gets to that line, because there's nothing here that would output it as lower case.

Comment: Actually there is: i understand why output is lowecase, but i cannot find the solution. Output is in lowercase because textToReplace is in lowerCase (since searchedText is 'def' in lowercase).

Comment: ... then something is making it lowercase before it gets to the template, which is precisely what I said. If you understand *why* it is lowercase then you should also be able to make it *not* lowercase, since it doesn't *need* to be lowercase in the template itself. What I *said* was that there's nothing here that would *output it in lowercase if it isn't already lowercase*.

Comment: In my exemple, on line 4, product.reference is "abcDeFg" and textToReplace is <span class='light'>def</span> (its 'def' in lowercase simply because user searched in lowercase). So the line that is doing replace will give me 'abc<span class='light'>def</span>g' -> simply because replace function is working like that. Problem is : how to keep in output the same sensitivity as in original value (product.reference)?

Comment: Don't blindly replace the text, instead find the start/stop indices of the string and build a new output string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression can do this alone:

```
${product.reference?replace(
     "(" + searchedText + ")",
     "<span class='light'>$1</span>",
     "ri"
)}
```

However, then `searchText` must not contain any characters that has special meaning in regular expressions (or those must be escaped).